# Search file within neotree in an unexpanded directory

Tags: search, neotree

Is it possible to search a file in neotree which is deep inside some directory?

The normal search only searches in the visible parts i.e., within directories that have been expanded. I am looking for a feature where it would search within all directories and expand a directory if needed.

For example, consider the folder structure

A > B > C

A > D > C

where A, B, C, D are folder names. When I open neotree, suppose that B and D are folded. Now if I search for C, I would like the fold of B to be opened and the cursor to jump to C. If I hit next, it should open D and the cursor should jump to C within D.

Comment: If you can give an example of what you are searching for, e.g., a filename or text within multiples, then someone may be able to write-up a solution if the feature you seek does not already exist.  Be specific as to a minimal working example so we can use it to base our tests off of.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question to include a minimal working example.  I opened up the neotree library https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/blob/dev/neotree.el and looked for some type of search mechanism for files and/or directories; however, I could not find anything.  Unless there is already some type of existing framework to build upon relating to searching for files and/or directories, it may be time consuming to create a new feature such as that.  That being said, sometimes forum participants are highly motivated.  I would suggest opening a Github issue / feature request.

Comment: Thank you for checking. I will open a feature request.